MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()`
I was creating a movie website and I was setting up a login I tried to register using POST through Insomnia which resulted in an error saying "MongooseError: Operation users.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms". I tried to solve as much as possible but so far not able to fix this issue. Can anyone help me fix the issue?


import userModel from "../model/userModel.js";

export default class AuthController{
  static async sendToken(user, statusCode, res){
    const token = user.getSignedToken(res);
    res.status(statusCode).json({
        success: true,
        token,
    });
  }

  static async registerController(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const { username, email, password } = req.body;
      const exisitingEmail = await userModel.findOne({ email });
      if (exisitingEmail) {
        return next(new errorResponse("Email is already register", 500));
      }
      const user = await userModel.create({ username, email, password });
      this.sendToken(user, 201, res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      next(error);
    }
  }

  static async loginController(req, res, next){
    try {
      const { username, password } = req.body;
      if (!username || !password) {
        return next(new errorResponse("Please provide email or password"));
      }
      const user = await userModel.findOne({ username });
      if (!user) {
        return next(new errorResponse("Invalid Creditial", 401));
      }
      const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        return next(new errorResponse("Invalid Creditial", 401));
      }
      this.sendToken(user, 200, res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      next(error);
    }
  }

  static async logoutController(req, res, ){
    res.clearCookie('refreshToken');
    return res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        message:'Logout Successfully',
    });
  }
}




Usually this error indicates, that the database connection was not established  by the time you use your model.
documentat
You need to do the following:

make sure that mongo database is up and running
You establish connection to database with mongoose.connect with valid connection string, i.e: mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')

related question
I assume you're using express.js for your website (based on tags you provide with the question). You can organize your code in such a way that the express application starts only after the connection to mongo is successfully established.
somewhere in index.js
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

async function main() {
  const {PORT, DB_CONNECTION_STRING} = process.env;    
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(DB_CONNECTION_STRING, {
       // other connection options
    });

    // setup your express app and run it
    const app = express()

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`server started`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
};

main();



I don't use .env and instead I use index.js



import app from './server.js'
import mongodb from 'mongodb'
import reviewsDAO from './dao/reviewsDAO.js'

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
const mongo_username = process.env['MONGO_USERNAME']
const mongo_password = process.env['MONGO_PASSWORD']
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${mongo_username}:${mongo_password}@cluster0.as4w6t7.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

const port = 8000

MongoClient.connect(
  uri,
  {
    maxPoolSize: 50,
    wtimeoutMS: 2500,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
)
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  .then(async client => {
    await reviewsDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })



Let me know if I need to create an env file or make changes in index.js
